# VIM: how to change case of accented characters with 'gU'?

Tags: vim, case, diacritics, uppercase, lowercase

Following sentence contains all accented characters (chars with diacritic) that are used in Czech language.

> příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy

Now I convert this line to uppercase using gUU and I get:

> PříLIš žLUťOUčKý Kůň úPěL ďáBELSKé óDY

instead of:

PŘÍLIŠ ŽLUŤOUČKÝ KŮŇ ÚPĚL ĎÁBELSKÉ ÓDY

As you can see the characters with accents don't get converted. What do I have to set in my .vimrc to get it working right?

Comment: Works without modifications on my system. Are you running in a UTF-8 locale.

Comment: Works on GVIM 7.3.823 on Windows. What's your Vim version and platform? Also, `:set encoding?`

Comment: I have GVIM 7.4 on Win XP 32bit. `:set encoding` returns: encoding=cp1250

Comment: There was [a bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_dev/y2IwXq0cVDs) in 7.3, fixed now.